Can 1 Samuel 16:23 be considered a manifestation of God? Can this evil spirit of God be considered as another person of God?
1 Samuel 16:23 Aramaic Bible in Plain English

And whenever the evil spirit of LORD JEHOVAH was on Shaul, David took
and he played on the harp and refreshed Shaul, and it was good for
him, and the evil spirit passed away from him.


This is a theological question that yields various answers depending on opinions and hermeneutical methods brought to bear. Here are several answers.

No because there is no evil in God.
No because, while God is the author of evil as well as good, this particular spirit was not part of God but a different person, who was nevertheless under God's direction.
Yes, because if we accept the YLT's literal translation, this spirit seems to be is an aspect of God rather than an independent entity.

In considering the issue, one should be aware that the Hebrew Bible itself (without the New Testament) tends toward the proposition that God is responsible for bad things as well as good. He is absolutely sovereign and to suggest that evil spirits are not under his orders is to descend into an unacceptable dualism. This idea is taught clearly in the Book of Job, although it may be seen elsewhere as well. We get a hint of this attitude in the NT as well when Jesus teaches that God sends rain on the just as well as the unjust, etc. (Matthew 5:45) The attitude that evil is completely outside of God's domain seems to have emerged during the Bablyonian Exile and the intertestamental period, when apocalyptic literature developed alongside of Jewish demonology. In the New Testament it is quite evident, with Satan appearing no longer as God's consultant (is in the Book of Job) but his enemy (as in the Book of Revelation and elsewhere) who is capable of opposing His will.
Conclusion: The answer depends more on theology than hermeneutics. Few people would consider the evil spirit mentioned in the OP to be a manifestation or "person" of God. However, the idea that God is responsible for evil spirits as well as good angels is not as unusual in Judaism as it is in Christianity.

Sometimes there is an unwarranted mix up between "a" spirit, "the" spirit, and "the Holy Spirit". The third Person of the Holy Trinity is never seen because he is Spirit and remains invisible, with his role being to glorify the second Person and point all to Christ. So, when this spirit in the text in question is worked out in king Saul as Saul's evil and violent (manic?) behaviour, it cannot be assumed to be the Holy Spirit. The question asks if, then, it is another spirit of God.
The answer begins to unfold in the previous chapter. This recounts Saul's disobedience to God, and happens before the priest, Samuel, anoints young David to be the next king. Saul's disobedience in doing sacrifices instead of Samuel is described as gross sin:

"Lo, hearkening than sacrifice is better; to give attention than the
fat of rams; for a sin of divination [is] rebellion; because thou hast
rejected the word of Jehovah, He also doth reject thee from [being]
king." 1 Samuel 15:22-23 YLT

Yet Saul was God's anointed king, so, due to what he had done, Samuel anointed young David to be the next king - in waiting. Saul would first have to die before God's rejection of Saul would be seen in the nation to have reached its bitter end. And consider how it was the sin of divination that directly led to Saul's death!
But back to the verse in question. This evil spirit was an initial consequence of Saul's rebellion against God. Holy Spirit would not prevent this happening. On the contrary, that evil spirit is said to come from God. But God was not manifesting himself through this; nor was the Holy Spirit manifesting himself through this. No, the evil that was already in Saul was "triggered", one might suggest, through no restraining spiritual help from God, and God actually showing Saul the beginning of what it meant to be rejected by God. Things only got worse for Saul thereafter, yet instead of repenting, his evil became ever worse, culminating in sin that proves the extent of Saul rejecting God's word - divination. Truly, an evil spirit began to get a visible grip on Saul right till he died.
When young David played soothing music on his harp for the agitated Saul to listen to, this anointed lad had an influence for good which the spirit of evil in Saul was subdued by. Not that it ever went away. It remained in Saul and got stronger in influencing the unrepentant Saul till he finally reaped the rebellion against God that he had sown. In that sense, the events of evil after that first rebellion could be said to have "come from" God. Usually, God just leaves the rebellious to their rebellion, to sink further and further into their mire of sin, but Saul was God's anointed king. The nation had to take note of what God would do with this man in his unique position in God's nation. Saul's evil became ever more clearly manifested.
So, the answer to the question is that this spirit of evil was not God manifesting himself, but the evil that gripped Saul manifesting, due to his disobedience, and that this spirit was not another 'person' of God.

Does this mean that the spirit of God that appeared in the form of a dove when Jesus was baptized was not the Holy Spirit?

@DanFefferman  Indeed it was the Spirit of God, for John the Baptist was told that upon whom he saw the Spirit descending and remaining, that one would baptise with the Holy Spirit. All holy. No evil. Clear distinction and a unique instance to identify Christ to John the Baptist at the start of his ministry. No link with 1 Samuel 16:23.

So this would be an exception to your statement; "The third Person of the Holy Trinity is never seen"?

@DanFefferman  John the Baptist seems to have been the only one who saw this, but the Holy Spirit did take on a visible form that once, so, yes, an exception to my statement. I'm always prepared to agree that my statements (as opposed to the ones in holy scripture) may require allowing for "an exception"!

It depends on what "to be seen" means. There was something visible in Matthew 3:16 (as there was something audible in the following verse). This doesn't contradict the idea that the spiritual realm is unseen and outside of our world. When spirits manifest in our world, it must be detectable in some way, right?

@TheChaz2.0 Ah, you posted this 1 minute after I posted my last comment! Good point.
